# go: var declared but not used error - how to work around it?

Tags: go

In this function I get ***"s declared and not used"*** which I don't understand - do I need to somehow tag it as 'really I used it' or something?

```
func getString(data map[string]interface{}, name string) (string, error) {
    s := data[name]
    if reflect.TypeOf(s).Kind() != reflect.String {
        return s.(string), nil
    }
    return "", &apiError{1, "it's not a string"}
}
```

Oddly, I don't get the error from this function:

```
func getInt(data map[string]interface{}, name string) (int, error) {
    t := data[name]
    if reflect.TypeOf(t).Kind() == reflect.Int {
        return t.(int), nil
    }
    return 0, &apiError{1, "it's not an int"}
}
```

Also, any thoughts on the right way to factor these into a single function would be welcomed!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error. Are you sure there's nothing else around causing it? https://play.golang.org/p/OpqqN7cBFZ

Comment: What do you mean by "factor these into a single function"? `getString` reads a string out of a map and returns it. `getInt` reads an int out of a map and returns it. In Go, these are very different behaviors.

Comment: Might there be a different "s" somewhere in your code that's confusing you?  (Hint: Use more descriptive varnames).

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from (declaring and not) using the same identifier elsewhere because this compiles and runs fine on `golang.org`:

```
package main

import "reflect"

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    m["foo"] = "25"
    getString(m, "foo")
}

func getString(data map[string]interface{}, name string) (string, error) {
    s := data[name]
    if reflect.TypeOf(s).Kind() != reflect.String {
        return s.(string), nil
    }
    return "", nil
}
```

Comment: err ma gerrrd. In my defence, it was nearly midnight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, error isn't reproducible.
Sure you can refactor these into a single function, but you may not like it depending of tastes.

```
type VType int
const (
    VInteger VType = iota
    VString
    VUnknown
)
func getValue(data map[string]interface{}, name string) (VType, int, string) {
    switch v := data[name].(type) {
    case int:
        return VInteger, v, ""
    case string:
        return VString, 0, v
    default:
        return VUnknown, 0, ""
    }
}
func main() {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    m["foo"] = "25"
    switch t, i, s := getValue(m, "foo"); t {
    case VInteger:
        fmt.Println("int ", i)  //do something with int
    case VString:
        fmt.Println("string ", s) //do something with string
    case VUnknown:
        err := &apiError{1, "it's not an int"} //do something with err
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it's questionable whether this is an improvement on the situation.